# Why doesn't DbgPrintEx support floating-point numbers?

Tags: c++, c, windows, kernel, device-driver

According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543634(v=vs.85).aspx)

> The `DbgPrintEx` routine does not support any of the floating point types *(%f, %e, %E, %g, %G, %a, or %A)*

That seems very strange, since they support most of the other C-style formatting parameters, and since `vsprintf` *(which is also available to kernel-mode drivers)* does support floating-point.

Is there a technical reason for not supporting floating-point numbers?

Comment: I suppose MS assumes that kernel-mode drivers have limited or no legitimate use for logging floating-point numbers, and decided to leave them out to keep the code lean and simple(r).  Indeed, you can work around the omission in the event that you really want to log an FP number.

Comment: Well one difference between `DbgPrintEx` and `vsprintf` is that the former is a Windows API function that probably doesn't or won't get into saving the state of the floating point registers, while the latter is a C++ runtime function, i.e.  it is part of whatever runtime library your compiled C++ program is using and possibly does this work of saving the state (I don't know, since I don't do kernel driver work).

Comment: AFAIK if you wish to play with FPU in the kernel, you have to save/load FPU state by yourself because the kernel does not do that. MS probably decided that kernel drivers do not need to work with FPU (SSE is a similar case; state of SSE registers is also not saved). When using vsprintf and similar functions, be aware of the IRQL restrictions placed on some wide-character formats (see the documentation for DbgPrintEx for details) because they probably apply for all these formatting functions.